# The assignment problem in Plot function

Tags: assignment

I used Mathematica to plot a system of equations:
Plot[{y = 2 x - 3, y = x/2}, {x, -5, 5}, Axes -> True,
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabels -> {"2x-y=3", "x-2y=0"}]

After the Plot, y is assigned to the value of 2.49828, which I can under stand why. But I don't understand why x is still remain as a symbol. How come this two difference?  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: To do the plot, just do `ClearAll[x, y];
Plot[{2 x - 3, x/2}, {x, -5, 5}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabels -> {"2x-y=3", "x-2y=0"}]`  also note that `=` is an assignment, not an equation, which uses `==`.  When using `=` Mathematica assigned to `y` the value on the rhs.  `x` remains a symbol, because it was not assigned any value.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! In Plot function, we only need to right the rhs of the function. I was influenced by the habit from python.

Comment: You can use equations if you use `ContourPlot`, e.g., `ContourPlot[{y == 2 x - 3, y == x/2}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -13, 7}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.3, .8}]]`

Comment: Big thanks! I learned much more than my question!